# Geonetwork Empty Geographic bounding box

Tags: extents, metadata, geonetwork

I set up Geonetwork 3.02 while creating a metadata geographic bounding box and spatial extent is empty. How can I fix these problems ? I use turkish language.
Can you help me please?

[image: Geographic bounding box]

Answer (score 1):

Does it happen in English too?

If not, probably it is because the Turkish language is not finished in that part. Right now it is at 53%, you can volunteer to translate here: https://www.transifex.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/

Comment: No it doesn't. I can see the list in English. Do you know which file i need to translate for this part ?  Also spatial extent box and geographic bounding box is empty in both of languages. Could you show me the relevant files about this from github what can i do about that? Thank you very much.

Comment: If I remember it right, the countries are from a Thesaurus. Can you check it on your installation? You can find them inside the admin.console.